# Implement promoted documents in Solr

Tags: solr

Is there a way to implement promoted (aka "Ad") documents in Solr using one request?

Requirements:

1. Ad documents are regular documents with the ad=true flag.
2. Ad documents are dynamic (a document can change Ad status frequently).
3. Ad documents should have their ranking logic (another set of boosts and groupings)
4. Ad documents should have its set of filters

Ad documents should be returned together with regular (non-promoted) documents.

Every page of results must have N number of Ad documents (for example 3), the rest should be the regular listings.

We're currently achieving what we want with making two requests, one for Ad documents, then another request for regular documents (with excluding filter to not show ad documents in regular documents). But doing it in one query could be very helpful.

We're trying to replicate the Google Ad behavior where for every page of results they show 5-6 ads (at the top and the bottom). The paid links on Google are taken from a pool of paid links and shown on a page together with organic items. If an Ad link is shown on a page, it is not shown in Organic results.

Comment: Did you already check out [the Elevate Creator Plugin](https://github.com/kaismh/solr-elevate-creator)? Nothing official though.

Comment: I didn't, thanks for the link, @cheffe

Comment: @ValentinVasilyev   Have same case. Remember how you managed to resolve ?

Answer (score 3):

> **Query Elevation Component**
>   The Query Elevation Component lets you configure the top results for a given query regardless of the normal
>   Lucene scoring. This is sometimes called "sponsored search," "editorial boosting," or "best bets." This
>   component matches the user query text to a configured map of top results.

**[elevate.xml]**

```
<elevate>
<query text="foo bar">
<doc id="1" />
<doc id="2" />
<doc id="3" />
</query>
<query text="ipod">
<doc id="MA147LL/A" /> <!-- put the actual ipod at the top -->
<doc id="IW-02" exclude="true" /> <!-- exclude this cable -->
</query>
</elevate>
```

In this example, the query "foo bar" would first return documents 1, 2 and 3, then whatever normally appears for
the same query. For the query "ipod", it would first return "MA147LL/A", and would make sure that "IW-02" is not
in the result set.

#### The forceElevation Parameter

You can force elevation during runtime by adding **forceElevation=true** to the query URL:
**[solrconfig.xml]**

```
    <searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
<!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
<str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
<str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
</searchComponent>
<requestHandler name="/elevate" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
</lst>
<arr name="last-components">
<str>elevator</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this approach will not work for us. I was aware about query elevation but it's a manual approach and when you have millions of documents and their Ad status changes frequently this approach is not practical.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to achieve with Solr. It does not give any built-in methods to pin top 3 slots.